# How to position absolute in scrollable area? (Css)

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position, absolute

I have this tricky CSS problem: I have this HTML and CSS:

```
.mark {
     height: 30px;
     width: 30px;
     background: red;
     position: absolute;
     left: 30px;
     bottom: 30px;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mr_mohsen_rasouli/4Nb9L/

I want to red box stay in define position but when I scroll, it move!

how can I fix that?

Comment: can you explain your problem clearly?

Comment: Well you should place the mark outside the scrolling area, but i'm not sure what you want to achieve exactly

Comment: The question is vague, where do you want the red square?

Comment: i test that but i wana to `mark` relative to `contentArea`. fixed position relate the mar to the page(body element) i want the `mark` element stay in `contentArea`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.. this may not be a good approach.
But will give you the desired result.

I place the `div mark` in another `div`
and give

```
.mark {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background:red;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Full code is here
http://jsfiddle.net/4Nb9L/7/

Answer (score 1):

you have used absolute,use fixed instead

```
.mark {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    left: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `position : fixed` and top reference  for the `.mark` element

Example:

```
.mark {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    left: 30px;
    top:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the value of position property fixed instead of absolute and try.

Comment: i test that bau i wana to `mark` relative to `contentArea`. fixed position relate the mar to the page(body element) i want the `mark` element stay in `contentArea`

Answer (score 0):

```
.mark {
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
background: red;
position: fixed;
left: 30px;
bottom: 30px;
}
```

Link : [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nb9L/4/)